# ef core add-migration separate assembly for data and domainmodel

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, visual-studio-2017, onion-architecture

I have three projects in (VS2017 and ef core) and want to run Add-migration.

- Web - Startup
- Core - DomainModel - here are the entitys
- Data - Context and migrations here. And dependes on ef core

The domainmodel have the entities and I want to have the migrationfiles/ output folder in a data project together with my context file.

I want to avoid having dependecies between domainmodel and entity framework. EntityFrameworkscore only have dependecies to Data.
Any suggestions how to run add-migration with this setup to get the migrationfiles in data instead of core/domainmodel?

Add-Migration -Name InitMigration -OutputDir Migrations -Context myDBContext -Project Business\Core

Comment: Just run your `Add-Migration` command without the `-Context myDBContext -Project Business\Core` part from the Data project and you should be fine.

Comment: Thanks it was too easy. I just remove -Project and then it worked as i wanted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to @joakimja the solution was to run:

`Add-Migration` command without the `-Context myDBContext -Project Business\Core` arguments.